# How to get dots in between equation and equation numbers with equation is centrally aligned?

Tags: equations

Add dots between equation and equation numbers without changing the equation's default center position?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

That seems a little strange but can be achieved with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
\hskip \textwidth minus \textwidth 
e=mc^2
\leaders\hbox{ . }\hskip \textwidth minus \textwidth
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please use `E` rather than `e` in the formula... :-)

Comment: @Mico You have edit rights:-)