# How to add dot after equations before the number?

Tags: equations, numbering

I am writing a paper for an IEEJ journal, and they require that after the equation, there should be dots before the equation number.

It should look something like this

[image]

The publisher provided a custom class in their website(http://denki.iee.jp/?page_id=5962) and using their class, the equation looks fine, as shown in the following example

```latex
\documentclass[english]{ieej-e}
%\documentclass[english,letter]{ieej-e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    a=1
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and the result looks like
[image]

But, when the `amsmath` package is loaded, the dots are not produced anymore, as shown below,

```latex
\documentclass[english]{ieej-e}
%\documentclass[english,letter]{ieej-e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    a=1
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the `readme.pdf` from the download custom class file, they provided a solution, adding `\rlap{\hbox to 10mm{\ \EqnDots}}` to the equation, but one has to **manually adjust** the length of width to get a satisfactory result for different equations, for example

```latex
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    a=1 \rlap{\hbox to 64mm{\ \EqnDots}}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        a=1234\rlap{\hbox to 58.5mm{\ \EqnDots}}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to add the dots automacally?

Comment: Probably interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110094/134144

Comment: do they _really_ want that??? that is just weird.

Comment: There is a custom class available on the paper website http://denki.iee.jp/?page_id=5962
The style for equations already gives the required result

Comment: @BambOo well spotted, and the class uses some code from Donald Arseneau (`dotseqn.sty` which is in texlive/miktex)

Comment: @BamOo, yes, I went to the website and downloaded their custom class.  They use dotseqn.sty to generate the dots. However, it is also mentioned that if the amsmath package loaded, it won't generate the dots automatically..

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. That looks close, but the dots are a little off, not aligned with the equations.

Comment: @Dunzhi but if the publisher provides a class for author submission shouldn't you just use that class and let the publisher worry about the exact layout?

Comment: Oh I just noticed that @leandriis link goes to an answer of mine:-)  That is aligned but I used `.` so it is on the baseline, your image shows `\cdot` so replace `\hbox{ . }` by `\hbox{ $\cdot$ }` in that answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes that is the idea. But their custom class is not working properly. I will update the problem with an example.

Comment: @Dunzhi, why do you require the `amsmath` package ? I mean, doesn't the original class support `equation` environments ?

Comment: @BamOo, yes, but I would like to use ```align``` environment from the ```amsmath``` package.