# How to fill dots between equation and tag(equation numbers) in align environment?

Tags: equations, align

Actually I searched this forum already and found some helpful answers under this link:
[How to get dots in between equation and equation numbers with equation is centrally aligned?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110088/how-to-get-dots-in-between-equation-and-equation-numbers-with-equation-is-centra)

I applied these tricks in an **equation** environment

```
\def\equation{\old@equation\small\hskip\textwidth minus 0.87\textwidth}
\def\endequation{\hbox{ }\leaders\hbox{$\cdot\,$}\hskip \textwidth minus
 \textwidth\old@endequation}
```

It works fine in this new **equation** environment. However, when I tried to use these tricks in an **align** environment, it does not work. I also tried to rewrite the **\maketag@@@** macro as following:

```
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hskip -\textwidth \leaders\hbox{ }\hskip 0.5\textwidth \hbox{} \leaders\hbox{$\cdot\,$}\hskip\alignsep@\hbox{\m@th\normalfont#1}}
```

It works some how not so perfectly, because some '...' overlaps with the equation:
[image]

And after defining the **\maketag@@@** macro, the **equation** environment is also destroyed.
[image]

What I really want is the equation looks like this picture:
[image]

I know there is a trick to realize this function in **align** environment like this:

```
\begin{align}
  e^x&=1+x\multido{\i=2+1}{6}{+\es{\i}}\notag\\
  \hskip 0.1\textwidth
     &\multido{\i=8+1}{6}{+\es{\i}}+\cdots\leaders\hbox{$\cdot$\,}\hskip
     0.18\textwidth\hskip
     -0.18\textwidth\label{eq:etoXseries}     
\end{align}
```

But I think it is not user friendly, because I must add additional codes in each line. I want to realize this function in the **align** environment, which means one can use like this:

```
\begin{align}
  e^x&=1+x\multido{\i=2+1}{6}{+\es{\i}}\notag\\
       &\multido{\i=8+1}{6}{+\es{\i}}+\cdots
     \label{eq:etoXseries}     
\end{align}
```

and the align environment will fill `$\cdot$` between the equation and number automatically.

I hope that I have explained my questions clear enough for you all.

Waiting for your answers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have the `dotseqn`  package for that.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. dotseqn works in equation environment, but it does not work in **align** environment. By the way, my editor also need the equation to appear in the **center** position.